# Unable to run audit2allow located in android source code

Tags: python, android-source, selinux

Location of `audit2allow` python script is `external/selinux/prebuilts/bin/audit2allow`

When I try to run the script, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shobhit/Desktop/Code/aosp/msm8909_android/external/selinux/policycoreutils/audit2allow/audit2allow", line 24, in <module>
    import sepolgen.audit as audit
  File "/home/shobhit/Desktop/Code/aosp/msm8909_android/prebuilts/python/linux-x86/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sepolgen/audit.py", line 20, in <module>
    import refpolicy
  File "/home/shobhit/Desktop/Code/aosp/msm8909_android/prebuilts/python/linux-x86/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sepolgen/refpolicy.py", line 22, in <module>
    import selinux
  File "/home/shobhit/Desktop/Code/aosp/msm8909_android/prebuilts/python/linux-x86/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selinux/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    _selinux = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/shobhit/Desktop/Code/aosp/msm8909_android/prebuilts/python/linux-x86/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selinux/__init__.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_selinux', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /home/shobhit/Desktop/Code/aosp/msm8909_android/prebuilts/python/linux-x86/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selinux/_selinux.so: undefined symbol: selabel_partial_match
```

Comment: What Android version are you on?

Comment: Thanks for replying, Android 6.0

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but...

Was a python version issue on my machine. Changed the `python` link to point to `python2` instead to `python3` and everything worked fine. Maybe there is a more elegant solution than to (temporarily) change links, but it worked, though.

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks. But the weird thing is that audit2allow is using python from the HOST machine and not from the AOSP package.